# Restful web services with tomcat 8

Tags: web-services, http, netbeans, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to make a simple example of restful web services  and it doesn't work for me. First, i'm using Netbeans for it, I'm using tomcat 8.5.20 and Java EE 7 web and i just have two classes. One is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyu7J.png)
And the other is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkgvS.png)

My intex.html has nothing apart the normal things and my context.xml just has this:
   [context.xml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxVdO.png)

just that.

The web service works pretty nice on my computer, but, when i deploy it in a server which use Apache Tomcat 6.0.45 i have a 404 error and i don't know why because it's the same path that i use when i prove it in my computer. [When i use the web service in my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IskM.png) vs [When i prove it in the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZqvL.png).

Thanks for the help, sorry for the bad english :v

Comment: please provide the Netbeans version you are using and copy the classes code as text (abbreviated to show only relevant parts) instead of images (even without descriptions...) so we can better help you.

Comment: ok, thanks, i'm new in this, so i don't know how to use this very well

Answer (score 0):

Nebeans version: 8.2

Class 1:

```
import rest.Consumo;
import co.edu.udea.exception.OrgSistemasSecurityException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/semestres")
public class HistoriaAcademicaResource {

   @GET
   @Path("/hola")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String hola()  {
      return "Don't give up";
   }
}
```

---

Class 2:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("prueba")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

---

Index:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SIRVE MALDITA SEA</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>SIRVE PLOX</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/pruebaREST"/>
```